# Unable to show the image stored in Shared folder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to show the image that is stored in the Shared folder of my project in a view. The image stored

[image]

I am trying to show this image on the View like below

```
<h7 style="text-align:center;">HAPPY @Model.Holiday </h7>
<br/>
<br/>
<p style="text-align:center;"><img src="../Shared/HappyHoliday.jpg" alt="Happy Holiday"></p>
```

Image shows up corrupted like below and also the center alignment is not working in both the image and the h7 tags

[image]

I even tried doing the src as  `src="./Shared/HappyHoliday.jpg"`  even that doesnt work. What is that I am missing here

Comment: Add static files to the wwwroot folder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @L01NL Does the image have to be in the wwwroot folder ? cant I just store in the Shared folder of the project and use them?

Comment: You can change the webroot folder by using the `UseWebRoot` method. You can call this method on the `WebHostBuilder` in your program.cs.

Comment: maybe because of permission? shared folder has special permission, I think.

Comment: @urlreader I have permission on the folder as I am using other componnents within the folder without any issues

Comment: In `asp.net core` it woundn't work like this way. Either you have to move your file inside `wwwroot` folder or you have customize your `UseStaticFiles` middleware you can [have look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `app.UseStaticFiles();` to

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Views/Shared")),
                RequestPath = "/Images"
            });
```

And then use `RequestPath` to get the image:

```
<h7 style="text-align:center;">HAPPY @Model.Holiday </h7>
<br/>
<br/>
<p style="text-align:center;"><img src="../Images/HappyHoliday.jpg" alt="Happy Holiday"></p>
```